# Beginning automation testing from scratch

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How far a manual tester can upgrade himself to learn automation testing(java, selenium webdriver, testng).

which programming will be easy for stepping into scripting for beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade yourself as much as you desire. There might be limitations on how quickly you can do it - due to your ability to find out time, level of interest and how things are at work.

In my experience, like any other language (french, german, hindi, etc.), each programming language has its semantics and syntax. The more time one spends practicing them (writing small programs, not reading from a book) the quicker one learns the language.

Being widely used and around for a long time, the support and learning avenues available for Java are much more so the process of getting help might be easier. 
Java is also very helpful if you are trying to pick up selenium webdriver.

The task and scope of learning a scripting language becomes very specific when trying to learn it for automation testing. Usually, you will be able to get through solving fairly complex issues if you master the following concepts in Java:

- OOP’s concept – Class, Objects Polymorphism, Inheritance and Encapsulation
- Java Programming essentials- Object Instances, method overloading/overriding concepts and packages
- Control Statements – While, do-While, Switch, If statements.
- Looping statements - Helpful in scenarios like, iterating through a large table to find a record that you want and running the same test for multiple number of times
- Arrays Concepts.
- Java Collections Framework – ArrayLists and HashMaps – This will help us in maintaining a collection of data. Particularly useful for scenarios where you need to compare the data from Web app UI with the DB. [OR] From UI to another UI
- File Streams – Used for externalization of data through CSV, Excel or Java Properties file.
- Threads and MultiThreading Concepts – This will be helpful when trying to run scripts in different threads that will help in achieving better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Answer: Keep going to Stack Overflow. Read as much as you can, then go try it.

If you want a start, these are good to read up on:

Test format: TestNG

Text Editor: Visual Studio Code

Ruby Application Testing:
RSpec, Capybara, Selenium, Cucumber, Nightwatch, etc... etc...

React Application Testing: Jest

Java Application Testing: Apache Maven (Makes setting up the project easy), Java, Selenium

CI/CD: Jenkins